# How writing a very large dictionary to a json file?

Tags: python, dictionary, nlp, bigdata, tf-idf

Please tell me what am I doing wrong. I want to create a dictionary from a lot of data. I have a file of 200,000 articles that contains 125,000 unique words, it looks like this:

```
data = [[['article_1', 'city', 0.43], ['article_1', 'big', 0.38], ['article_1', 'beautiful', 0.25]], 
        [['article_2', 'sun', 0.65], ['article_2', 'beautiful', 0.41], ['article_2', 'shining', 0.21]],
        [['article_3', 'big', 0.72], ['article_3', 'beautiful', 0.50], ['article_3', 'butterfly', 0.25]]]
```

That is, each list is a separate article, which consists of lists: [article_number, word, word weight (tfidf)].

I need to get a dictionary of the form:

```
{'city': [('article_1', 0.43)],
 'big': [('article_3', 'big', 0.72), ('article_1', 'big', 0.38)],
 'beautiful': [('article_3', 0.50), ('article_2', 0.41), ('article_1', 0.25)],
 'sun': [('article_2', 0.65)],
 'shining': [('article_2', 0.21)],
 'butterfly': [('article_3',0.25)]}
```

I'm trying to create a dictionary by immediately writing it to a json file (in google colab), but this uses all the RAM, and as a result, the google colab environment is disabled. I use this code:

```
with open('drive/MyDrive/dictionary.json', 'w') as f:
    d = defaultdict(list) 
    [d[i[1]].append((i[0],i[2])) for j in data for i in j]
    dct = dict(d.items())
    dct = dict(sorted(d.items()))
    f.write(json.dumps(dct) + '\n')
```

Tell me, please, what am I doing wrong? Or maybe it is better to store such a large amount of data in some other way?

Comment: Problem happens at file write or at the data processing?

Comment: I don't know, just a few seconds pass and the memory runs out and the collab environment reloads

Comment: You first need to identify the point of failure. Please put some print statements inside file write operations and check. If it is at `f.write`, I'd suggest writing the data in chunks

Comment: Colab has limited resources to begin with. Perhaps you should use Spark mllib to distribute the workload and chunk the data. Spark can also do TF-IDF. But also, you're running a list comprehension that needlessly creates a list of all `None` elements, which is discarded

Comment: Write to your json file over a loop and append one item at each time. That means you do not store the whole dictionary but read it line by line and then write to the json file line by line.